# Animation not stopping on hover using webkit-animation-play-state

Tags: css, animation

Hover doesnt work. When the mouse hovers the div, the animation must stop and never start again. I would prefer a non-jQuery solution.

CSS:

```
 .box:hover { -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;}
```

Check a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/j52qz6v4/).

Comment: Please give your question a descriptive title, such as "Animation not stopping on hover using webkit-animation-play-state".

Comment: The hover is not specific enough, move `.box:hover` to the very end and you're done. Also, [you don't usually need prefixes anymore](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation).

Comment: @misterManSam i updated jsfiddle but when mouse leave the div, div continue animation.But i want to stop animation of the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to achieve a one-time hover without JavaScript or jQuery:

CSS:

```
.one_time {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function hoverOnce(target, type, listener) {
    target.addEventListener(type, function fn(event) {
        target.removeEventListener(type, fn);
        listener(event);
    });
};

hoverOnce(document.getElementById("myelement"), "mouseover", function (event) {
    document.getElementById("myelement").className = "one_time";
```

});

jQuery:

```
$(".button-color-2").one("mouseenter", function(e){
    $("#myelement").addClass("one_time");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem no.1:
Your animation is overriding your animation-play-state. To fix that put your hover after it. Check a working demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/j52qz6v4/1/).

Problem no.2:
You can't do that without JavaScript, as there is no CSS selector for "once hovered".

CSS:

```
@keyframes ilkDenemem{
    0% {margin-left: 0}
    100% {margin-left: 300px}
}

@keyframes dondur{
    0%{ transform: rotate(0deg);}
    50%{transform: rotate(360deg);}
}

.box{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background: #000;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}


.box:nth-of-type(1){
    -webkit-animation: ilkDenemem 2s infinite,
    dondur 2s infinite;
}

.box:nth-of-type(2){
    -webkit-animation: ilkDenemem 1s alternate infinite; 
    -webkit-animation-delay :2s; /*Chrome, Safari , Opera*/
}

.box:nth-of-type(3){
    -webkit-animation: ilkDenemem 2s 1 ease-in; 
}

.box:nth-of-type(4){
    -webkit-animation: ilkDenemem 2s 1 ease-out; 
}

.box:nth-of-type(5){
    -webkit-animation: ilkDenemem 2s 1 ease-in-out; 
}

.box:nth-of-type(6){
    -webkit-animation: ilkDenemem 2s 1 steps(5); 
}

.box:nth-of-type(7){
    -webkit-animation: ilkDenemem 2s 1 cubic-bezier(0,1,.95,0); 
}

.box:hover {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Comment: can u post me solution of problem 2 with js